# Why it's not a good idea to hold an instance with out first copying it via its copy constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, cascading

I was trying to understand Cascading. So I started reading the documentation and found this line, "**Since Tuples are mutable, it is not a good idea to hold an instance around with out first copying it via its copy constructor, a subsequent Pipe could change the Tuple in place**. " 
I don't know what it means? Why it's not a good idea to hold an instance with out first copying it via its copy constructor? 
Would like to see some examples?
Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the values in the `Tuple` that you're holding can change unexpectedly because of something that happens in a subsequent `Pipe`. But if you copy the `Tuple` using its copy constructor, and then hold on to the *new* instance, then you have the only copy and nothing else can change it.